# typescript class method type annotations are not being exported

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, types

I have a class definition in the file `cso-api.ts`:

```js
export default class CsoAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  async getNamePopularityDataByYear(year:number): Promise<NamePopularityData> {
    ...
```

As this function is annotated as having a return of type `Promise<NamePopularityData>` then why do I not get a warning/error when I import in a second file and  I assign it to a string?

```js
import  CsoAPI from '../apis/cso-api';
...
const nameData:string = await CsoAPI.getNamePopularityDataByYear(year)
```

Also VSCode shows the wrong type when hovering over the imported function:
[image]

Comment: What type do you have If you hover over `CsoAPI`?

Comment: @АлексейМартинкевич doesn't show a type just `(alias) class CsoAPI
import CsoAPI`

Answer (score 0):

`getNamePopularityDataByYear` is an instance method as per the given definition of the class `CosAPI`. To use it, we should be invoking it over an instance of `CosAPI`, like...

```
const nameData: string = await new CsoAPI().getNamePopularityDataByYear(year);
```

If we want to use it the way as mentioned above, then we will have to qualify the function `getNamePopularityDataByYear` with `static` keyword, like...

```
...
static async getNamePopularityDataByYear(year:number): Promise<number> {
...
}
```

Choose what way to use that function and adjust accordingly.

Comment: thanks Nalin I got it to work as a static method. I was actually instantiating elsewhere (and I accidentally edited out while trying to make the issue clearer) so it seems it will import the type info as a static method but not as an instantiated class method. Probably something I am not understanding in typescript ...